# Multilingual Linux logins?

Tags: linux, login, language

@MODS!!
I attempted to add a comment to provide further information and seek clarification from the one person who answered.  I cannot add a comment due to being new.
Thus, I posted an "Answer" and referenced the fact that I can't add a comment and didn't feel that an Edit is the appropriate way to go.  This "Answer" was deleted.
Then I performed an edit, commencing with this opening: "@RalfFriedl Thanks for this thought. Being new, I can't add a comment, and posting it as an "answer" was deleted."

Two moderators both Rejected the edit with the reason "add a comment."

So please tell me - given the inability to do the ONLY three possible ways to seek clarification - how the hell is one supposed to seek clarification!?  Thanks for nothing!!

RHEL 7

When I telnet to this Linux box, I receive a Login and Password prompt in English - the server's default LANG = en_CA.utf-8.  Which is great for all of the English speakers, but not so great for the French speakers; more particularly, when there's an error (Login incorrect) or notification (Warning: your password will expire in x days; You must change your password now).

I've tried doing export LANG="fr_CA.utf-8" in ~/.bash_profile; ~/i18n.  As this is not yet a Production server, I also tried putting that in /etc/profile;  /etc/security/pam_env.conf; and other places that I honestly don't recall now.  But in each case, I only got English notifications.  (After actually being logged in, Linux errors/messages were then in French.)  So no file that I could find, was early enough in the login sequence of events.

Telnet is required, as connection is actually via an MFC GUI Client which only supports telnet.  (If there's something with ssh that I can pass LANG, I can probably hardcode in an encrypted .piv to have everyone telnet/login as 1 user and then perform an ssh login to prompt for specific user credentials.)

1. Perfect world scenario: there's something that I can do to set language /before/ logging in;
2. Acceptable world scenario: login/password (and failures) are in English, but the instant the user has been validated, have LANG set appropriately (based on username or IP address range) to display messages in the desired language.

As a sidenote - though this would be a separate question - windows telnet has French character display issues when connected to Linux; I am attempting to get the MFC to connect using PuTTY Telnet.

Thanks
Rick

Answer (score 0):

If you use telnet to login, you have to modify the environment of the telnet server, specifically set `LANG` before you start telnet. Most new distributions use systemd, where you can set environment variables before starting a service.

It should be possible for you to start two telnet servers on different ports with different settings of `LANG`. Then your users just have to know which port to select to get their language.